# C# overwrite first few lines of a text file with constant time

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file:

```
FIRST LINE
SECOND LINE
THIRD LINE
...
```

I want to overwrite the first line of the file, eg. with `"2345"`
with the StreamWriter, I can only overwrite the file into:

```
2345
```

with

```
using (StreamWriter newWriter = new StreamWriter(playingFileDirectory, false)){ 
    newWriter.WriteLine("2345");
}
```

or

```
FIRST LINE
SECOND LINE
THIRD LINE
...
2345
```

with

```
using (StreamWriter newWriter = new StreamWriter(playingFileDirectory, true)){ 
    newWriter.WriteLine("2345");
}
```

However My desired result is:

```
2345
SECOND LINE
THIRD LINE
...
```

Is there any quick way (linear time) of doing that?  I have some text that need to be updated whenever the user presses a button.  The database records contains 100,000 lines. I just want to change the first line like in a text editor, but not changing 1 line and rewriting the whole file.

Comment: You have to rewrite the entire file if you want to replace an arbitrary number of bytes not at the end of the file. The filesystem can't "move up" or "move down" the remainder of the file depending on how many bytes you want to insert.

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort. A simple google found lots of similar questions and answers.

Comment: @Liam sadly the response you pointed doesn't show any effort in answering :-) It doesn't explain *why* you can't directly do it.

Comment: This question just smells too much of, *I've been given this homework question and I can't be bothered figuring out the logistics so someone else can do it for me* @xanatos Maybe I'm wrong but..

Comment: I am self learning and experimenting with c#, and I googled a while but failed.  Actually I want a solution with O(1) time, because O(n) time methods will take quite long for very large files.

Comment: and this is my first post in stackoverflow, and I was expecting an answer in a day or two.  Anyway, thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that is possible out-of-the-box. I would suggest to do the following:

- Open the output file for writing;
- Write your first few lines;
- Open the input file for reading;
- Read up to the line you need;
- Read the line from input and write it to the output;
- Close both.

If you need to, you can first move the input file and write the output file to the original location.

I would advise against the use of `File.ReadAllLines` if the file is large. It will have an enormous impact on your memory.

Answer (score 3):

Read and write the file in terms of lines:

```
    var allLines = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile");
    allLines[0] = "2345";

    File.WriteAllLines("MyFile", allLines);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("YOUR_PATH");

lines[0] = "2345";

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("YOUR_PATH", lines);
```

[Read all lines method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Write all lines method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Downvoted as it's a direct duplicate of James Lucas' answer and was posted later, so should be deleted to avoid clutter.

Comment: @DavidArno: Is that a valid downvote reason? It was posted the exact same minute...

Comment: @PatrickHofman, maybe not. So I've removed it.